# How to know what is exported from a module?

Tags: node.js, node-modules

So far I have seen different ways of using modules in node.js.

1. Exporting object from a module:

   ```js
   var http=require('http');
   http.createServer(<callback function>).listen(<port>)
   ```

   Here the `http` module exports an object which can be used to call its methods
2. Exporting constructor functions:

   ```js
   var eventEmitter=require('events');
   var obj= new eventEmitter();
   ```

   Here the word `new` is used as a function constructor is returned. And we can use methods of `eventEmitter` through object `obj`.
3. Exporting functions:

   ```js
   var connect=require('connect');
   var obj=connect();
   ```

   Here function is exported from module `connect` and the function returns an object. The object can be used to call its methods.

My question is how to know what is exported? How to know if we need to create an object for whatever is exported from the module using the `new` operator, or if the function exported returns an object or if the module itself exports an object.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, one would read the documentation for the module they are using and use the syntax provided. However if you are trying to do this programmatically:

A module export can be anything, think of it as any other javascript variable. Like other javascript variables you can use the [typeof operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) to distinguish its type between object and function. If it is a function you can test if it is a constructor like so

```
  try {
    new myFunction();
    console.log("myFunction is a constructor");
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("myFunction is NOT a constructor");
  }
```